# Is there any way to parse and fetch color text data from JSON in kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am trying to parse and fetch data from JSON. But, I want at the place of color name respective color should be displayed.

e.g.

```json
  {
        "id": 1,
        "name": rose,
        "color": "Red"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": lily,
        "color": "White"
    }
```

So, at the place of text red: Red color and for white: White color and so on.

Comment: The `parseColor()` suggestion below is clever. It won't work for all arbitrary color names of course. In general this kind of mapping can be done with "lookup tables". In Java it could be a `Map` with a `String` (color name) as the key and a numeric/string color value as the value as in `0xFFFFFFFF` or `"#FFFFFF"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Color` class method:

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

in android.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more field in json which would contain hex color code.

```
{ "id": 1, "name": rose, "color": "Red" , "code" :"#ff0000" }, { "id": 2, "name": lily, "color": "White" , "code" :"#ffffff" }
```

Then parce this hex code using Color function **parseColor**.

Comment: Thanks. Can call this as backup option. I am looking to do this without making changes to the current data. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so